# Section header element should occupy zero vertical space

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, textpos, zref

My goal is to split a diagram across two facing pages, as such:

[image: split diagram]

The left-hand page will additionally have a `\section` or `\subsection` above the diagram. In order to make the two halves of the diagram line up properly, it's important that the section or subsection header on the left-hand page occupy zero vertical space. Otherwise, the left half would be pushed down and not match the right half.

So I'm trying to devise a way to force force the section header (or, ideally any arbitrary content) to occupy zero space. I found the following solution somewhere, unfortunately I can't recall where:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\noverticalspacelen}

% Insert a command so that it occupies no vertical space, future text overlaps
\newcommand{\noverticalspace}[1]{%
\setbox0=\vbox{{#1}}%
\setlength\noverticalspacelen{\ht0}%
\box0
\vspace{-\noverticalspacelen}%
}


\begin{document}

% Should overlap XXXX on top of Header
\noverticalspace{\section{Header}}
\section{XXXXX}


% Should overlap XXXX on top of Content
\noverticalspace{Content}
\par XXXXX

\end{document}
```

The above code makes sense to me: we measure the content in question, then use `\vspace` to remove the space that it occupies. If this code works, I would expect to see XXXX overlapping the Header and Content text. It almost works:

[image: not overlapping]

I'm not sure why this is. I tried an alternative version, which first sets various spacing measures to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\noverticalspacelen}

% Insert a command so that it occupies no vertical space, future text overlaps
\newcommand{\noverticalspace}[1]{%
\parskip=0pt
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\parindent=0pt
\renewcommand\bigskip{}
\renewcommand\medskip{}
\renewcommand\smallskip{}
\renewcommand\bigbreak{}
\renewcommand\medbreak{}
\renewcommand\smallbreak{}

\setbox0=\vbox{{#1}}%
\setlength\noverticalspacelen{\ht0}%
\box0
\vspace{-\noverticalspacelen}%
}


\begin{document}

% Should overlap XXXX on top of Header
\noverticalspace{\section{Header}}
\section{XXXXX}


% Should overlap XXXX on top of Content
\noverticalspace{Content}
\par XXXXX

\end{document}
```

This version comes maddeningly close:

[image]

I can't explain why these approaches don't work. Is there a "correct" approach for what I'm trying to do? I've experimented with `zref-savepos` which seems like it would help but it doesn't. I also tried the `textpos` library with similar unsuccessful results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be surprisingly tricky to place a box in a way that doesn't affect the surrouding content It isn't enough to make it zero sized. Especially if it is followed by headings or other display constructs that explicitly look back at the previous item and adjust the space they add. A heading following a box for example will add more space than a heading followed by a heading (which has already added space).

Also boxing a heading, will interfere with its control of the following paragraph.

So I would not use that stratgy but rather simply add negative space to account for the heading. You could dissect the code of the heading commands to see what space is required but simpler to let TeX show you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

% Should overlap XXXX on top of Header
\section{Header}
\section{XXXXX}


% Should overlap XXXX on top of Content
Content
\par XXXXX

\section{Header followed by text not header}
ZZZ

\end{document}
```

produces a log showing

```
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 r
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{\protect \numberli
ne \ETC.}
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 9.90276 plus 0.86108
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 8.12001
...\hbox(9.87999+0.0)x345.0, glue set 259.53334fil
....\hbox(9.27998+0.0)x24.29997
.....\glue 0.0
.....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 2
.....\glue 16.19998
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 X
```

after the firt Header

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 292.49992fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 X
```

after Content

and

```
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 r
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{\protect \numberli
ne \ETC.}
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 9.90276 plus 0.86108
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.3667
...\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x345.0, glue set 326.66666fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Z
```

after the final section head.

So

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

% Should overlap XXXX on top of Header
\section{Header}

\vspace*{-9.90276pt plus -0.86108pt}
\vspace{0pt plus -1pt}
\vspace{-8.12001pt}
\vspace{-9.87999pt}% height of next box as shown in log
\section{XXXXX}


% Should overlap XXXX on top of Content
Content

% in the next two could also compensate for parskip,
% but as that has natural length 0pt here don't bother

\vspace{-\baselineskip}% easier here as XXX isn't "clever" about adding space
XXXXX

\section{Header followed by text not header}

\vspace{-9.90276pt plus -0.86108pt}% glue after heading
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
ZZZ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, using fixed numeric values seems inflexible and likely to break if I change the settings of my document. Is there a way to determine why Latex is inserting this:
`\vspace{0pt plus -1pt}\vspace{-8.12001pt}\vspace{-9.87999pt}`

Comment: Also, how did you get that log output?

Comment: @Wicker the log shows that, as the auto-inserted spaces ar named 0pt plus -1pt is `\parskip` and the others are essentially `\baselinskip` or the pre or post space added by laex. From your use case you don't actually need that complication as you ar not trying to overlay two headings, just a heading with an image, which is like my last example. That is just the after heading space from the section head so would be the same for any section

Comment: @Wicker Every time you run tex it writes a `.log` file with the same name as your main file with `.log` instead of `.tex`  I just looked at that. (actually this information also appears on th terminal when tex is running due to the `\showoutput`

Comment: I'm looking at the `.log` file as well as the terminal output but I don't see anything that looks like that. I'm using `xelatex` if it makes any difference. All I see is a catalog of included packages and some warnings about Underfull `\hbox`. Do I need to enable some flag to see the low-level log output?

Comment: @Wicker`\showoutput` shows the box output on each page, see the preamble in the above